# Mathematica gives invalid generators of a group?

Tags: group-theory

```
generators = GroupGenerators[SymmetricGroup[4]];

CayleyGraph[SymmetricGroup[generators], VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
  VertexSize -> 0.4];
```

I came across this hilarious error while playing around with Cayley Graphs. The above simple program yields the following error:

> CayleyGraph:SymmetricGroup[{Cycles[{{1,2}}],Cycles[{{1,2,3,4}}]}] is
> not a valid group.

Now since I'm using the generators Mathematica itself gives me, the only thing I can think of to explain this is some type of syntax error, but nothing appears to be wrong.  I'm sure there is a simple solution I'm missing but for the life of me, I can't see it.

Comment: `SymmetricGroup` takes a non-negative integer as an argument, not group generators. So `CayleyGraph[SymmetricGroup[4], VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> 0.4]` works.

Comment: Perhaps you mean `CayleyGraph[ PermutationGroup[generators] ]`?

Comment: Ahhh that's it.  I knew I was missing something, thanks for the help!